# Variation in RSSI values

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to measure the RSSI (level values in dBm) using

```
        wifi.startScan();
        List<ScanResult>results= wifi.getScanResults();
```

A timer is set to repeat the scan for every 100ms.

The RSSI values obtained at a particular location in the same time from Samsung I9070(Android 2.3.6) and Samsung S3 I9300 (Android 4.1.2) wrt to a wifi router differ by a range of 20 db.

Can someone tell me whether the RSSI values vary with the wifi chipset and android OS version?

Comment: Of course.  And add antenna, antenna orientation, and reflections/nulls in the immediate RF environment to the list.  These are phones, not field strength meters.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for the reply. But,the readings were taken at the same time. Two phones were kept next to each other and wifi router was not disturbed.

Comment: And the wavelength of the signal is a fraction of the size of a phone.